# Работа с итераторами. Пустые параметры

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных, итераторы

Написать программу учета заявок на обмен квартир и поиска вариантов обмена. Каждая заявка содержит сведения о двух квартирах: требуемой (искомой) и имеющейся. Сведения о каждой квартире содержат: количество комнат, площадь, этаж, район. Программа должна обеспечивать выбор с помощью меню и выполнение одной из следующих функций:

• ввод заявки на обмен;

• поиск в картотеке подходящего варианта: при совпадении требований и предложений по количеству комнат и этажности и различии по показателю «пло-щадь» в пределах 10% выводится соответствующая карточка и удаляется из списка, в противном случае поступившая заявка включается в картотеку;

• вывод всей картотеки.

Для хранения данных картотеки реализовать и использовать контейнерный класс list.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <list>
    #include <fstream>
    #include<clocale>
    #include<iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    struct Kvartira
    {
         string raion;
         int kolvokom;
         int plosh;
         int itash;

    };
    struct KvartiraI
    {
         string raion2;
         int kolvokom2;
         int plosh2;
         int itash2;
    };

    template<class T> bool operator==( list<Kvartira>& List, list<KvartiraI>& 
    ListI ); template<class T> bool operator!=( list<Kvartira>& List, 
    list<KvartiraI>& ListI );

    typedef list<Kvartira> KvartiraList;
    typedef list<KvartiraI> KvartiraListI;
    typedef list<Kvartira>::const_iterator ConstIterKvartiraList;
    typedef list<KvartiraI>::const_iterator ConstIterKvartiraListI;




    void Print(const KvartiraList& List)
    {
        ifstream file("isk.txt");
        cout<<file.rdbuf();
        cout<<endl;
    }

    char MainMenu()
    {
        system("cls");  

        cout << "меню:" <<endl;
        cout << "\t 1. добавить заявку" << endl;
        cout << "\t 2. напечатать весь list" << endl;

        char item = 0;
        cin >> item;

        return item;
    }
     KvartiraI DataInputI(const KvartiraListI& ListI)
     {
         std::ofstream
        fout("isk.txt",std::ios::app);
        KvartiraI kvartiraI;
        getline(std::cin, kvartiraI.raion2);
        cout << "этаж : ";
        cin >> kvartiraI.itash2;
        cout << "площадь: ";
        cin >> kvartiraI.plosh2;
        cout << "кол-во комнат: ";
        cin >> kvartiraI.kolvokom2;
        fout<<"район ";
        fout<<kvartiraI.raion2;
        fout<<" этаж ";
        fout<<kvartiraI.itash2;
        fout<<" площадь ";
        fout<<kvartiraI.plosh2;
        fout<<" количество комнат ";
        fout<<kvartiraI.kolvokom2;
        fout<<std::endl;
        fout.close();
        return kvartiraI;
     }
    Kvartira DataInput(const KvartiraList& List)// Ввод данных
    {
        std::ofstream
        fout("isk.txt",std::ios::app);
        Kvartira kvartira;
        cout << "район: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(std::cin, kvartira.raion);
        cout << "этаж : ";
        cin >> kvartira.itash;
        cout << "площадь: ";
        cin >> kvartira.plosh;
        cout << "кол-во комнат: ";
        cin >> kvartira.kolvokom;
        cout << "район: ";
        cin.ignore();
        fout<<"район ";
        fout<<kvartira.raion;
        fout<<" этаж ";
        fout<<kvartira.itash;
        fout<<" площадь ";
        fout<<kvartira.plosh;
        fout<<" количество комнат ";
        fout<<kvartira.kolvokom<< '\n';
        fout<<std::endl;
        fout.close();
        return kvartira;
    }




void poisk(KvartiraList& List,KvartiraListI& ListI,KvartiraList& kvartiraList,KvartiraListI& kvartiraListI,Kvartira& kvartira,KvartiraI kvartiraI){

    for(ConstIterKvartiraList iKvartira = kvartiraList.begin(); iKvartira != kvartiraList.end();++iKvartira){
        for(ConstIterKvartiraListI iKvartiraI=kvartiraListI.begin();iKvartiraI!=kvartiraListI.end();++iKvartiraI){
            if(kvartira.raion==kvartiraI.raion2 && kvartira.kolvokom==kvartiraI.kolvokom2 
                && kvartira.plosh==kvartiraI.plosh2 &&  kvartira.itash==kvartiraI.itash2){
                cout<<"заработало";
            }
        }}
 };
    int main()
    {
    KvartiraList List;
    KvartiraListI ListI; 
    KvartiraList kvartiraList;
    KvartiraListI kvartiraListI;
    Kvartira kvartira;
    KvartiraI kvartiraI;
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        size_t n = 0;

        char answer = 'y';
        while (answer == 'y')
        {
            switch (MainMenu())
            {
            case '1':
               kvartiraList.push_front(DataInput(kvartiraList));
               kvartiraListI.push_front(DataInputI(kvartiraListI));

                break;
            case '2':
                poisk(List,ListI,kvartiraList,kvartiraListI,kvartira,kvartiraI);
                break;
            case '3':
                Print(kvartiraList);
            default:
                cout << "такого пункта не существует." << endl;
                break;
            }
            cout << "нажмите'y'для возврата в меню\nнажмите другую клавишу,чтобы выйти ";
            cin >> answer;
        }

        return 0;
    }
ПРИ РАБОТЕ НА ЭТО УЧАСТКЕ ВСЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ РАВНЫ НУЛЮ И ПОЭТОМУ ВСЕГДА РАВНЫ


for(ConstIterKvartiraList iKvartira = kvartiraList.begin(); iKvartira != kvartiraList.end();++iKvartira){
            for(ConstIterKvartiraListI iKvartiraI=kvartiraListI.begin();iKvartiraI!=kvartiraListI.end();++iKvartiraI){
                if(kvartira.raion==kvartiraI.raion2 && kvartira.kolvokom==kvartiraI.kolvokom2 
                    && kvartira.plosh==kvartiraI.plosh2 &&  kvartira.itash==kvartiraI.itash2){
                    cout<<"заработало";
                }
            }}
```

Comment: Что в итоге то? Что не работает? )

Comment: @Suvitruf подходящий вариант всегда будет находится так как любой из параметров равен -858993460, а значения район вообще пустые, соответственно попарно равны